# How to show data with zero value every month

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, group-by

I have "MySQL Query" with a table of data items in 1 year. I want to display based on month grouping.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(create_date) AS month, COUNT(*) AS cplan FROM nota_jual GROUP BY month
```

[image: Result from my query]

I want the data displayed to include items with a value of 0 every month.

```
month       cplan
January     3       
February    2       
March       0       
April       0       
May         0       
June        0       
July        8       
August      8       
September   6       
October     3       
November    5       
December    3
```

can some one help /answer this? (Thankyou)

Comment: Are you only every worried about the month (i.e. which year the month belongs to does not matter)?

Comment: The simplest method is if you have a calendar table or list of the months you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
SELECT date_format(tn.create_date,'%m') as Month, count(*) as cpplan
FROM nota_jual tn
GROUP BY Month
ORDER by Month;
```

Comment: That is still not going to generate MONTH's for which the OP does not have data recorded on his table :) Which is of course the point of the question